# What is the Silverlight's FindElementsInHostCoordinates equivalent in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, hittest, visualtreehelper

I would like to perform a rectangual hit test on WPF Canvas component in order to get Controls that are overlapped by a Rectangle framework element. I found a Silverlight's `VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates` method, but apparently it's not available in WPF.

What's the best method to achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest equivalent is [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753.aspx). It works significantly differently to Silverlight's `FindElementsInHostCoordinates`, but you should be able to use it for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have a call like this in Silverlight

```
var result = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(myPoint, myUIElement);
```

then this WPF code should have an equivalent `result`

```
var result = new List<DependencyObject>(); 
                         //changed from external edits, because VisualHit is
                         //only a DependencyObject and may not be a UIElement
                         //this could cause exceptions or may not be compiling at all
                         //simply filter the result for class UIElement and
                         //cast it to IEnumerable<UIElement> if you need
                         //the very exact same result including type

VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(
    myUiElement,
    null,
    new HitTestResultCallback(
        (HitTestResult hit)=>{
            result.Add(hit.VisualHit);
            return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
        }),
    new PointHitTestParameters(myPoint));
```

in your special case you might want to use `GeometryHitTestParameters` instead of `PointHitTestParameters` to do a Rect-Test.